# Preferred Python way of getting the item of a set with a length(/cardinality) of one without removing it?

Tags: python, set, member, cardinality

Given set *s*, which of the segments below looks better?

```
if len(s) == 1:
    v = s.copy().pop()
    # important stuff using variable v takes place here
```

or

```
if len(s) == 1:
    v = s.pop()
    s.add(v)
    # important stuff using variable v takes place here
```

or

```
if len(s) == 1:
    for v in s:
        # important stuff using variable v takes place here
```

I guess the last segment is the most efficient, but doesn't it look silly to use a loop that never actually loops?

Why don't python sets have an alternative method to pop that doesn't remove the item?

This may seem like a trivial question, but as I've run into this scenario multiple times it has become an itch in need of scratching!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the only element to `v` like this:

```
(v,) = the_set
```

It raises a exception if `the_set` doesn't contain exactly one item.

Comment: @Will: It iterates through the right side directly, same as detly's `v = next(iter(s))`.

Comment: Also possible without the parentheses: `v, = the_set`.

Answer (score 5):

> Why don't python sets have an alternative method to pop that doesn't remove the item?

If you want to access the first (and only) item without changing the set structure, use an iterator:

```
v = iter(s).next()
```

This works prior to Python 3. In Python 3, you need to use the built-in `next` function:

```
v = next(iter(s))
```

Comment: you can't do `some_set[0]` because sets have no order.

Comment: How do you -1 the person who gave a +1 :)

Comment: Arg, I totally missed the `set` vs `list` distinction! Changed now!

Comment: @Will Buddha - in Python 2.6, `iter(set([1])).next()` works. In Python 2.7, `iter({1}).next()` works. Apparently you're using Python 3.0, for which I've updated my answer.

Comment: @detly: It's apparent that he's using Python 3.x; nobody but nobody uses Python 3.0